# No top bar or graph shown on Gephi

Tags: gephi

It's the first time I'm using Gephi (version 0.9.2) and when I enter I get this screen.

[image]

Now when I select one of the .gexf files everything seems to go smoothly...

[image]

, but then I click on "Accept" and no graph is shown, and clicking on any of "Overview", "Data Laboratory" or "Preview" is useless.

[image]

I'm stuck and according to [this tutorial](https://gephi.org/tutorials/gephi-tutorial-quick_start.pdf) I should be able to see the graph and have some bars available.

Note I previously had to change the path in the `gephi.conf` file to `jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1"` as suggested [here](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/1787). I'm using Windows 11.

Comment: My Gephi installation works in Windows 10 without setting "jdkhome" and with a newer Java. Can you open one of the Samples available through menu Window>Welcome. One example is `Les miserables.gexf`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to upgrade your Gephi version. From version 0.9.5 Gephi no longer requires Java installation and shows other improvements.

With this upgrade this problem should be solved as mentioned in this post about a similar issue:
*"The latest version of Gephi (0.9.3) embed Java (JRE11) on Linux as well so no need anymore to install Java separately. This should solve most Java compatibility issues"*
https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/1997

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).